# "URL not defined in the manifest" when running Instant App that uses @string for host name

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-instant-apps

Seeing issue running Instant App in Android Studio when `@string` value is used for host name (getting "URL not defined in the manifest"  error).  For example:

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="@string/SOME_DOMAIN" />
```

This is working fine if `android:host` is set to raw domain string.  I can work around this by setting that value to specific domain value when running/debugging from AS but not ideal (always danger of pushing code that contains the hard coded string!)

Also, this works fine if I build/deploy base and feature apks from command line and trigger using something like `adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "<my url>"`

Comment: had tried that but no luck....looks like AS requires hard coded string in `android:host`

Comment: Note that this works if I build/run from command line.....it correctly interprets `@string/SOME_DOMAIN` ...issue is only if I run from AS

Comment: I've filed this at http://issuetracker.google.com/68084954

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Until this is fixed, depending on your needs you can consider using [manifest build variables](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html) instead.

Comment: @Idolon I see issue if I use manifest build variables instead.

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly what is the issue with manifest build variables?

Comment: @Idolon Same as original issue reported when I use `@string` resource

Comment: I cannot post comments right now, hence an aswer. Today, the bug of [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863387/url-not-defined-in-the-manifest-when-running-instant-app-that-uses-string-for#comment80684795_46867821) that `<data ... />` inside an `<action />` does not support any string resources in Android Studio 3.1.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 still persists.

Answer (score 1):

as alternative you can use **[manifestPlaceholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html)**

```
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="${SOME_DOMAIN} />
```

in you build.gradle:

```
flavor {
   dimension "instant"
   manifestPlaceholders = [SOME_DOMAIN: "https://instantapp.example.com/"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because it's not the main

> Manifest.xml

, but the debug Manifest.. Try editing

> app/src/main/Manifest

**Note:** host name matching in the Android framework is case-sensitive, unlike the formal RFC. As a result, you should always specify host names using lowercase letters.

[Reference Android developer String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) is a bit unclear on whether `android:host`  can contain a string resource, or just a simple string:

```
<data android:scheme="string"
      android:host="string"
      android:port="string"
      android:path="string"
      android:pathPattern="string"
      android:pathPrefix="string"
      android:mimeType="string" />
```

But according to Google employee @dchai:

> String resources are supposed to be supported … This is a bug in Android Studio.

The bug in question has been fixed in Android Studio 3.2, so
now it's possible to use string resource and [manifest build variable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) as a value for `data` attributes.

Comment: String resources are supposed to be supported---Developer Console was updated to handle this case.  This is a bug in Android Studio.